# pandas: get the exact corresponding value with the corresponding index based on a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, indexing

I have a column of string(sentence) and a column of comma separated list of strings as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'text':['the weather is nice though', 'How are you today','the beautiful girl and the nice boy'],
'pos':[['DET', 'NOUN', 'VERB','ADJ', 'ADV'],['QUA', 'VERB', 'PRON', 'ADV'], ['DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN','CON','DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN' ]]})
```

and I would like to somehow compare the columns, and create a third column where if the 'pos' column contains the value 'ADJ', I would find its corresponding value in the 'text' column (in this case in the first row I have 'nice') and return its index as well in a form of a dictionary . so this is how the third column should look like;

```
third_column:

1 {'nice' : 3}
2 {}
3 {'beautiful':1, 'nice':6}
```

so far I have tried the following:

```
df['Third_column']= ' '
df['liststring'] = [' '.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['pos']]
df.loc[df['liststring'].str.contains('ADJ'),'text']
```

but do not know how to proceed to get the exact word and the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is exactly what [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) does.

If you want to calculate another column/row according to other columns/rows in pandas, this method should be considered.

```py
import pandas as pd


def extract_words(row):
    word_pos = {}
    text_splited = row.text.split()
    for i, p in enumerate(row.pos):
        if p == 'ADJ':
            word_pos[text_splited[i]] = i
    return word_pos


df = ...
df['Third_column'] = df.apply(extract_words, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of:

1. Getting the words and POS tags into individual (synced) columns:

   ```py
   df['text'] = df.text.str.split()
   df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
   ```

   ```
         text   pos
   0      the   DET
   0  weather  NOUN
   0       is  VERB
   0     nice   ADJ
   0   though   ADV
   ```

   (Note: Having lists, dictionaries, and other sequences as cells
   is mostly a sign that you need to restructure your data.)
2. Resetting the index, keeping the original index as 'sent_id' and adding sentence-wise indices to the tokens:

   ```py
   df['sent_id'] = df.index
   df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
   df['tok_id'] = df.groupby('sent_id').cumcount()
   ```

   ```
         text   pos  sent_id  tok_id
   0      the   DET        0       0
   1  weather  NOUN        0       1
   2       is  VERB        0       2
   3     nice   ADJ        0       3
   4   though   ADV        0       4
   5      How   QUA        1       0
   6      are  VERB        1       1
   7      you  PRON        1       2
   ```
3. Finally, getting all the `'ADJ'`-rows

   ```py
   df[df.pos.eq('ADJ')]
   ```

   ```
            text  pos  sent_id  tok_id
   3        nice  ADJ        0       3
   10  beautiful  ADJ        2       1
   14       nice  ADJ        2       5
   ```